# How to dynamically create tasks in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I can't figure out how to dynamically create tasks in airflow at schedule time. My Dag is created prior to the knowledge of how many tasks are required at run-time. I.e., On each dag trigger, i would like to pass the directory to be processed to create a list of tasks for the following Dag.

I couldn't come up with anything so far

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2004, 11, 12),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dyn_test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@once'
)


dir = '/home/uname/dir'
filesInDir = next(os.walk(dir))[2] 

for file in filesInDir:
    task1 = # change 'file' structure
    task2 = # store changed 'file'

    task1 >> task2
```

Here, how should i pass 'dir' variable while triggering the Dag so that task1 and task2 will run based on number of files present in the 'dir'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/concepts.html#variables) or Environment variables.

```
# Using Airflow Variables
from airflow.models import Variable
dir = Variable.get("dir")

# Using Env Vars
import os
dir1= os.environ["dir1"]

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2004, 11, 12),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dyn_test',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@once'
)


filesInDir = next(os.walk(dir))[2] 

for file in filesInDir:
    task1 = # change 'file' structure
    task2 = # store changed 'file'

    task1 >> task2
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, But how do i _set_ the variable before triggering the Dag through rest (and not from the UI).

Comment: You can use Airflow CLI. Currently it is not possible using API